# Installing geoR on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, install.packages, geor

I'm having issues installing the geoR package on ubuntu 16.04, when I run

```
>install.packages('geoR', dependencies = TRUE)
```

I get the following error message

```
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:141: recipe for target 'RFoptions.o' failed
make: *** [RFoptions.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RandomFieldsUtils’
* removing ‘/home/luca/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RandomFieldsUtils’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmph5zmhR/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RandomFieldsUtils") :
  installation of package ‘RandomFieldsUtils’ had non-zero exit status
> 
> install.packages('geoR', dependencites = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/luca/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘RandomFieldsUtils’, ‘RandomFields’

Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  unused argument (dependencites = TRUE)
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘RandomFieldsUtils’ failed
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  unused argument (dependencites = TRUE)
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘RandomFields’ failed
Error in download.file(url, destfile, method, mode = "wb", ...) : 
  unused argument (dependencites = TRUE)
Warning in download.packages(pkgs, destdir = tmpd, available = available,  :
  download of package ‘geoR’ failed
```

It seems to me that the issue is with the RandomFieldsUtils package, and also when I try to run

```
>install.packages('RandomFieldsUtils')
```

I get the same error

```
/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:141: recipe for target 'RFoptions.o' failed
make: *** [RFoptions.o] Error 1

ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RandomFieldsUtils’
* removing ‘/home/luca/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/RandomFieldsUtils’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmph5zmhR/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RandomFieldsUtils") :
  installation of package ‘RandomFieldsUtils’ had non-zero exit status
```

I'm pretty new to R and tried this both in R Studio and in the Ubuntu console, got the same message twice.

Any idea how to fix it?

thanks in advance

Comment: also try to install.packages("RandomFields")

Comment: It's the same error again also for this

Comment: what about http://www.leg.ufpr.br/geoR/geoRdoc/installpackage.html

Comment: Even installing the development version it has issues with the RandomFieldsUtils dependency.

I also tried to download the RandomFieldsUtils package source from
[CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RandomFieldsUtils/index.html)
and install it from there, but it gives the same error again.

Running out of ideas

Comment: well, use windows lol

Comment: (un)fortunately, that's not an option. But thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around a bit, I managed by downloading the second-to-latest version of RandomFieldsUtils (i.e. 0.3.16 instead of 0.3.20) directly from the contributor's [website](http://ms.math.uni-mannheim.de/de/publications/software%22website%22) and installing it from the package.

Posting this answer to myself in case it can help anybody!